# Android progress spinner loader stops spinning when the data starts fetching in background

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-volley

I am using a progress spinner on pre execute method of Async task to show it on UI and the data starts fetching in the background from Api using volley library.The problem is when it starts fetching the data,the loader stops spinning and its like the UI is not responding.

need help,Thanks in advance..
`
ProgressDialog dialog;

```
public void open() {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(BuzoongaContacts.this);
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_layout);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
}

public void stopLoading() {
    Log.d("res", "stopLoading ");
    try {
        dialog.dismiss();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}`
```

Async Task:

```
class BuzoongaContactsAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                open();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContactsDataTableOperations conDataTab = new ContactsDataTableOperations(BuzoongaContacts.this);
        conDataTab.open();
        JSONParsingForContactsB.count = 0;
        count = 0;

        if (fromRefresh) 
        {
            if (isInternetConnected()) {
                getBuzzongaContacts();
            } else {
                rl_sub_main_buzoongaContacts.startAnimation(animZoomOut);
                alertDialog("Network Error !",getResources().getString(R.string.network_error));
                rl_alert.startAnimation(animMoveUp);
            }
        } else 
        {
            if (getContactsExistence() == 0) {
                if (isInternetConnected()) {
                    getBuzzongaContacts();
                } else {
                    rl_sub_main_buzoongaContacts.startAnimation(animZoomOut);
                    alertDialog("Network Error !", getResources().getString(R.string.network_error));
                    rl_alert.startAnimation(animMoveUp);
                }
            } else if (Constants.buzoongaContactsAdded) 
            {
                if (isInternetConnected()) {
                    getBuzzongaContacts();
                } else {
                    rl_sub_main_buzoongaContacts.startAnimation(animZoomOut);
                    alertDialog("Network Error !", getResources().getString(R.string.network_error));
                    rl_alert.startAnimation(animMoveUp);
                }
            } else {
                stopLoading();

            }
        }
        arr_list = conDataTab.getAllRecords();
        conDataTab.close();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        cb_select_all.setChecked(false);
        iv_quick_launch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.quick_lounch_icon_disable);
        Constants.selected_buzoonga_contacts = 0;
        rl_delete.setAlpha(0.5f);
        rl_delete.setClickable(false);
        rl_show_contacts.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute` method code

Comment: Please post the entire AsyncTask

Comment: getBuzoongaContacs(); is a method,where I am fetching data using volley library.

Comment: @asifahmed: fist point is you are accessing ui views `alertDialog` others in `doInBackground` method

Comment: ok...it will access when their is no internet...but why the loader stops..!!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't touch your UI elements in background threads, which means that all your calls to `startAnimation()` or `stopLoading` should be wrapped with `runOnUiThread`.

But I can see your UI code is so bound up with your background code. Maybe you could consider using `Thread` & `Handler` instead of `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @songchenwen..that is ok...but I am calling my loader in pre executes and stops in post...using of UI element in the background will make the changes in loader???

Comment: @asifahmed As you mentioned your app seems not responding, I suspect you run your background code in your ui thread. Maybe you can put you code here, in which you start your async task.

Comment: @songchenwen...I mean,stops in spinning of loader looks the UI not responding.once the fetching done the spinner disappears(stopLoading)..

Comment: @songchenwen....I made my background to run on ui thread...but still I am finding the same problem...